# Not able to copy multiple files using rsync 3.0.9 version?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, rsync

I am trying to copy two files using rsync from a `machineB` but somehow it always copies only one file but not the second file -

Here is the syntax I am using -

```
rsync -avz david@machineB:'/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140317/t1_weekly_1680_0_200003_5.data :/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140317/t1_weekly_1680_1_200003_5.data' /data01/primary
```

It only copies this file `t1_weekly_1680_0_200003_5.data` into `/data01/primary` folder and it didn't copied second file which is `t1_weekly_1680_1_200003_5.data`.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and rsync version is -

```
rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30
```

This is the error I am getting -

```
receiving incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "/home/david/:/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140317" failed: No such file or directory (2)
t1_weekly_1680_0_200003_5.data

sent 30 bytes  received 504982813 bytes  6196108.50 bytes/sec
total size is 1761988281  speedup is 3.49
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1536) [generator=3.0.9]
```

I started reading the rsync manual but somehow I am not able to understand what wrong I am doing?

**Update:-**

It works fine on a single command if I run it from the console but I need to run that from the shell script so I added your suggestion in my shell script.

I just ran your suggestion on my below example and I got an error.

Below is the shell script which simply tries to copy file from `machineB`, if the files are not there in `machineB` then it should be there in `machineC` so it will try to copy from `machineC`. `PRIMARY_PARTITION` and `SECONDARY_PARTITION` will have file numbers.

And below shell script I am running on `machineA`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

readonly PRIMARY=/data01/primary
readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION=/bexbat/data/be_t1_snapshot
PRIMARY_PARTITION=(0 548)
SECONDARY_PARTITION=(1101 1374)

dir1=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]} \
  ls -dt1 "$MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] | 
  head -n1)
dir2=$(ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]} \
  ls -dt1 "$MEMORY_MAPPED_LOCATION"/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] |
  head -n1)

echo $dir1
echo $dir2

## Build your list of filenames before the loop. 
for n in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
do
    primary_files="$primary_files :$dir1"/t1_weekly_1680_"$n"_200003_5.data
done

## Repeat for $SECONDARY_PARTITION
for n in "${SECONDARY_PARTITION[@]}"
do
    secondary_files="$secondary_files :$dir2"/t1_weekly_1680_"$n"_200003_5.data
done

echo "Primary: " $primary_files
echo "Secondary: " $secondary_files


if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ]
then
    find "$PRIMARY" -mindepth 1 -delete

    # this line is giving an exception somehow
    rsync -avz david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}${primary_files} $PRIMARY/
    rsync -avz david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}${primary_files} $PRIMARY/

fi
```

Below is the error I got -

```
Unexpected remote arg: :/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140320/t1_weekly_1680_0_200003_5.data
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1232) [sender=3.0.9]
Unexpected remote arg: :/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140320/t1_weekly_1680_0_200003_5.data
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1232) [sender=3.0.9]
Unexpected remote arg: :/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140320/t1_weekly_1680_1101_200003_5.data
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1232) [sender=3.0.9]
Unexpected remote arg: :/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140320/t1_weekly_1680_1101_200003_5.data
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1232) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Comment: Also, because there's only a one character difference: --include="fi"[10]"le"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the looks of things, all you need to do is drop the quotes (line breaks added for clarity):

```
 rsync -avz \
   david@machineB:/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140317/t1_weekly_1680_0_200003_5.data \
   :/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140317/t1_weekly_1680_1_200003_5.data \
   /data01/primary
```

From the `rsync` man page:

```
The  syntax  for requesting multiple files from a remote host is done by
specifying additional remote-host args in the same style as the first, or with
the hostname omitted.  For instance, all these work:

          rsync -av host:file1 :file2 host:file{3,4} /dest/
```

The first two files in the copied example use the same syntax as you have, however they are separate arguments (quoting them concatenates them into a single argument). If your paths contain characters which need to be quoted you can do something like:

```
rsync -avz \
  'user@host:dodgy path/file_with_asterix*' \
  ':some_other/dodgy\\path' \
  /dest
```

#### Update

I think the simplest way to make your script work is just to use arrays for `primary_files` and `secondary_files`. The relevant changes for `primary_files` are:

```
for n in "${PRIMARY_PARTITION[@]}"
do
  primary_files+=( ":$dir1/t1_weekly_1680_${n}_200003_5.data" )
done

....

echo "Primary: ${primary_files[@]}"

...

rsync -avz "david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}${primary_files[@]}" "$PRIMARY/"
```

The `[@]` will split the array into different arguments regardless of quoting. Otherwise, mind your variable quoting, some of what you have may or may not cause issues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yeah it worked fine with your suggestion if I run it directly on the console with that single command but I need to run that from my shell script and if I use your suggestion, it is giving an error if I run it from shell script. I have updated my question with the shell script and what  I am doing.

Comment: Any thoughts what is going on?

Comment: @Webby, updated

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and when this line got printed out `echo "Primary: ${primary_files[@]}"` it is missing the file number  and other number after `1680`. For example this is what it is getting printed out - `/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140320/t1_weekly_1680_.data`. It is missing lot of numbers after `1680`.

Comment: @Webby, ok you want `${n}` instead of `$n`. Updated.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can see file getting copied. One quick question - I am using these two lines in my shell script `rsync -avz david@${FILERS_LOCATION[0]}${primary_files} $PRIMARY/
    rsync -avz david@${FILERS_LOCATION[1]}${primary_files} $PRIMARY/
`. Suppose if the file is not there in `machineB` then it will be copying the files from `machineC` in my script?. Am I correct?

Comment: @Webby, the second `rsync` will copy files from machineC regardless of what happened on the first one. If the files didn't exist they will be copied. They may also be overwritten.

Comment: @Webby - i attempted to address that in a code snippet though i had no practical means to test. Still, the idea was to build b list first and then only to add values from c if they didnt already exist in b.